# How to use *.a library in Android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to use [herumi / bls](https://github.com/herumi/bls-eth-go-binary/tree/master/bls) library in my application. I've successfully compiled libraries following his documentation and get a file `armeabi-v7a/libbls384_256.a`.

As I guess this is not the same with *.so library and I cannot use this library directly in JNI. I guess instead of this I have to create my own native code to import `libbls384_256.a`. Is it correct way?

There is no problem to use my own C++ code in my project and this part is already pretty described in different manuals. But I have no idea how to import `libbls384_256.a` to my native code using Android Studio, Gradle and JNI.

How to include `*.a` library in native code in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, you should write a shared library that links against the prebuilt static library. The shared library should contain the exported functions that you want to call from Java, and these can in turn call functions in the static library.

If you're using nkdBuild you'd use the `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` rule, and then add the library to the `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` for your shared library. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts

If you're using CMake you'd do something like:

```
add_library(bls384_256 STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(bls384_256
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION the/path/to/libbls384_256.a
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES the/path/to/the/bls384_256/api/headers
)
```